# Zend Plugin , register during predispatch but before action method is called

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to figure a way to call a plugin during predispatch, but I am having trouble calling it last.

Basically I need to call this after all controller predispatch, before the action method is called.

Is this possible?

I tried calling the plugin lastly by passing a high value, but I know this is wrong. I am not looking to call this on the postDispatch.

```
 $front->registerPlugin(new Plugin_Acl, 1000);

 class Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
 {
     public function preDispatch(...)
     {
       // ... DO STUFF before any action method
     }
  }
```

Comment: are you trying to call before any action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `Zend_Controller_Action` has an *empty* `preDispatch()` method which is called after `preDispatch()` on all front-controller plugins (which occurs before the controller is even instantiated) and then on all attached action-helpers, right before the action method itself. See the `dispatch()` methods on [Zend_Controller_Front](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.11.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FFront.php), [Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.11.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FDispatcher%2FStandard.php), and [Zend_Controller_Action](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.11.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FAction.php) for the flow.

So, if you want something to run at that point on *all* controllers, then you could create a base controller with a `preDispatch()` method containing the code you want to run.

Comment: Very good answer. Do you perhaps know what would be the difference with using a base controller with the same code in `init()`?

Comment: @Stardev: The `controller::init()` method is called when the controller is _instantiated_. When the requested action is then dispatched, it will fire `helpers::preDispatch()` and `controller::preDispatch()` (pardon my pseudo-code). So, I guess there is only a practical difference if any attached action helpers - either statically or during the `init()` itself - had `preDispatch()` hooks.

Comment: @slick: A good reference for the firing can be found at: http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks guys, thats exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing that in dispatchLoopStartup()

```
class My_Plugins_Front extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

        // Register ACL plugin if is admin controller (for eg.)
        if($request->getControllerName() == 'admin'){
            /**
             * Set up your ACL
             */
        }

        // You can setting variable to see in all view files
        $layout     = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $view       = $layout->getView();
        $view->test = 'test';
    }

    public function dispatchLoopShutdown(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calling in predispatch seems to work for my acl:

```
class Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        parent::preDispatch($request);
        //do some stuff
}
```

Then it instantiated in the application.ini with the line:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Controller_Plugin_Acl"
```

Hope this helps some...